# How to get key value from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I am using `Axios` to fetch data from API. From one page I am sending data through URL to another page which I want to use on another page.

```
http://localhost:3000/otp?email=test.k@gmail.com
```

I want to get the value of email.
In reacting project I am using react-router-dom, Axios, hooks.

Answer (score 2):

One solution using hooks:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const location = useLocation()
const email = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('email')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
```

You should use like below

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

You can use VanillaJS

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
const email = params.urlParams.get('email');
console.log(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom`, for example:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);

  return <div>{query.get('email')}</div>
}
```

It's also important to know the difference between params and queries in the routes.